# Magento get date format

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to get date format

```
<?php $DeliverBy = $_product->getData('productlength'); ?>
<?php $i=$DeliverBy;
echo  date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('Y')));?>
```

In this i add current date + same date based on attribute 
**productlength** is a textbox attribute it have some number. So the out put is current date + productlength

it's working fine. It display 
**12.12.2015**

But I want to `**`**12. Dec.2015**`**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php $i=$DeliverBy;
    echo  date("d.M.Y",mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('Y')));?>
```

Comment: what is the different beyween m & M

Comment: m  Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros  01 through 12,
M  A short textual representation of a month, three letters  Jan through Dec & 
n  Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros  1 through 12

Comment: ok thanks for your answer and explanation